# HLS Streaming media player for iPhone4

Tags: iphone, iphone-4, http-live-streaming

I am looking for a good HLS streaming media player for my iPhone-4.
I have developed one sample Http live media streaming server which stream MPEG2/TS transport stream and i want to test this server on iPhone4. For this i want one MPEG2/TS stream player. Where i will provide name of my HLS server and it will request playlist and then will play it accordingly.

Does anyone know simple HLS player for iPhone4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in media player in iOS (from 3.0) supports HLS.
You can type the m3u8 path in safari address bar and it will play it.